# Wrap and Fill parent layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout has 3 views (vertical) : View1, View2, View3.

I want that width of Root View be max witdh of View1, View2 and View3. But width of other views (not maximum width) be `fill parent`. How to do that?

Comment: Better put a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Set root view width as wrap_content. it should work for you.